# Leer bytes desde un socket en java

Tags: java, socket, tcp, stream, servidor

Estoy intentando hacer un servidor en java que lea bytes del socket.

El problema que tengo aquí es que la función *`read()`* me devuelve -1 y esto se puede dar al hecho de que la conexión se cierra.

No sé cual es el problema por el cual se cierra la conexión. Lo que hago en la clase principal es:

```
int port = -1;
ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(0);
port = socket.getLocalPort();
th r = new th(socket);
r.start();
```

En la clase que implementa el thread tengo lo siguiente:

```
public class th extends Thread  {
    public static ServerSocket sc;
    public static byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
    int p;

    public th(){
        sc = null;
    }

    public th (ServerSocket userSC){
        sc = userSC;
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("En la clase TH");
        Socket serverAddr;
        boolean condicion = true;
        DataInputStream in;

    for (p = 0; p < 256; p++) System.out.print(buffer[p] + " ");
        try {
            serverAddr = sc.accept();
            in = new DataInputStream(serverAddr.getInputStream());

            in.read(buffer);
            for (p = 0; p < 256; p++) System.out.print(buffer[p] + " ");
            int a = in.read(buffer);
            if (a == -1){
               Ssytema.out.println("ERROR");
            }
            for (p = 0; p < 256; p++) System.out.print(buffer[p] + " ");
            String res = new String(buffer);
            System.out.println(res);
            System.out.println("NO ESPERA");
            serverAddr.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e){
            System.err.println("Error creando socket");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: sulaiman, ¿obtienes algún error?, ¿obtienes algún resultado mas claro?. Actualiza tu código en el `catch` e imprime la Excepción capturada, así tendrás mas detalles de los posibles errores que tengas. Si tienes mas información que pueda ser útil para entender para la comunidad, te recomiendo [edit] tu pregunta.

Comment: No me da ninguna excepción, es decir, la conexión la genera bien, pero el read devuelve -1 y se supone que eso es por que la conexión se cierra pero en el try no salta una excepción al crear la conexión